# undefines reference to function in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class called Metadata, which is declared within the `namespace A::B::C`, which also contains the `struct copyInfo`, which holds the info about a metadata.
So, Metadata has only its default contructor / destructor, and when I try to use a member function from Metadata called 
    `importMetadata(vector<copyInfo> &info, const string &src, const string &dst, const int &job:`

I'm getting the following error:

```
import_helper.cpp:(.text+0x246): undefined reference to
A::B::C::Metadata::importMetadata(std::vector<A::B::C::copyInfo, std::allocator<A::B::C::copyInfo> >&, 
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, 
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int const&)
namespace A{
  namespace B{
    namespace C{
        class Metadata{
              Metadata();
              ~Metadata();
             importMetadata(vector<copyInfo> &seq, const string &src, 
                 const string &dst, const int &job);
             /* more code down here */
        };
      }
     }
    }
```

Now, in `Metadata` I have:

That function is being called from a wrapper c++ function called `wrapperMetadataImport`, which belongs to `import_helper.cpp`.

```
#include "Metadata.h"
using namespace A::B::C;

int wrapperMetadataImport(const char * src, const char * dest, const int * jobid){
        Metadata mtd;
        string src = srcName;
        string dest = destName;

        vector<copyInfo> sequence;

        /* add elemens to the vector sequence */

        if((ret = mtd.importMetadata(sequence,
                        src, dest, *jobid)) == EC_success){

        /* more code down here */
```

I have no clue why I'm getting that. I have checked the .h and .cpp file, everything sounds ok to me. I suppose it's a runtime linking problem. The namespacing should be as is: `A::B::C`. Any thoughts?

Comment: `const inst * jobid`: `inst` seems to be a typo. And where do you pull `trustedname` and `targetname` from?

Comment: Have you actually defined Metadata::importMetadata? Have you linked to the file where it's defined?

Comment: yes, I have importMetadata defined in `Metadata`

Comment: then it has a wrong signature.

Comment: Many, many flaws in that question. No code for `Metadata.cpp`. Compiler error says `import_helper.cpp` while question says `metadataimport_helper.cpp`. Code says `copySequency`while compiler error / question says `copyInfo`. Code used for compiling / linking the code not given. Please rework the question so people can reproduce your problem. (This is not in vain, quite frequently you will find the answer in the process yourself.)

Comment: @Karoly, that would give a compiler error not a linker error. I suspect the definition isn't qualified with the class name.

Comment: This wrapper has as goal to server as interface between an `import.c` file and `Metadata.cpp`. So I'm using `extern "C"` in other to make it work. So I don't suppose the function should be within `A::B::C namespace`

Comment: @philippe: You say you have `importMetadata` defined in `Metadata`, but the compiler seems to disagree. Could you show us the definition?

Comment: @DevSolar: This is a proprietary code, I'm sorry I can't share more info with you, so I tried to give you my best insight.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Question updated!

Comment: @philippe: You've shown us the *declaration*, but do you have a *definition* (i.e. the implementation of the function)? If you do, are you linking with the file that contains that definition? It certainly looks like it's either missing, or not being linked.

Comment: @philippe: There is nothing that could *possibly* be "proprietary" in a function `foo()` that calls a function `bar()`. We don't need any algorithmics here; actually we don't **want** algorithmics as it doesn't contribute to the linker problem. But we want to be able to see *your* problem on *our* machines. Preparing such a minimal example is a very good (!) debugging procedure. If it doesn't show you the problem, it will give you much more helpful answers by others much quicker. Right now, we're all guessing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a linker error, and indicates that the implementation of the function can't be found. Either you haven't written the function, or you haven't included the source file containing it in your build.

You have *declared* it in the class definition, but without a full *definition* the function can't be called.

Comment: I think you've got the point Mike. The `Metadata.cpp` is on the Build definition. The header of the `metadataimport_helper.cpp` contains the `Metadata.h` which should be enough. I agree with you: the linker it's not finding `Metadata.cpp`. But I don't know why, as I said it is on the Build. `metadataimport_helper.cpp` it's a wrapper between a `import.c` and `Metadata.cpp`, so I use `extern "C"` to call that from the .c file

Comment: @philippe: You are aware that 1) the linker needs to find `Metadata.o`, not `Metadata.cpp`, and that 2) something declared `extern "C"` is visible to the linker using standard **C** naming, while default C++ is visible to the linker using **C++** "name mangling".